# TensorFlow not installing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I cannot find a solution to TensorFlow setup for Python.
Every variation of 'pip install tensorflow' throws me this error:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement TensorFlow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for TensorFlow`

Also tried to build from source, as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#download_the_tensorflow_source_code

Still doesn't work and throws the same error at the end.

`>python --version
Python 3.6.5`

`>pip --version
pip 19.3.1`

Is anyone kind enough to help?

Comment: Try conda environment?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `pip` for `python3`? Can you try `pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow`?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to install python 64bit
it worked for me